# Discord.py not working after installing

Tags: python, api, bots

After installing discord.py from the command: -

```
python3 -m pip install -U discord.py
```

I cannot access or use the discord library from within any python programs. Is there something else that I have to do first?

Basically it finds an error when importing discord via "import discord".

Thank you

Comment: And what error do you get?

Comment: No module named discord

Comment: Did you get any errors during installation proccess ?

Comment: The issue was resolved. I had to reinstall python.  After that,  everything worked.

Answer (score 1):

1.reinstall python

2.try another thing to put into the cmd thingy

3.Are you running it as admin?

4.Just run the bot... it might work anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple problem.

Check these things then come back:

- Did you edit your enviromental variable to support `pip`?
- Did you install discord.py through `pip`?
- Are you using the correct version of Python? See [this](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/) for supported versions

Please read the [discord.py docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) if you have any other issues.

Thank you.